# join dataframes using parts of datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes with datetime index.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'dat': ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03'],'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1.set_index(['dat'], inplace=True)
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)

d = {'dat': ['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01'],'y': [10, 11]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2.set_index(['dat'], inplace=True)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
```

df1:

```
            x
dat          
2016-01-01  1
2016-01-02  2
2016-01-03  3
2017-01-01  4
2017-01-02  5
2017-01-03  6
```

df2:

```
             y
dat           
2016-01-01  10
2017-01-01  11
```

I would like to join them using only year and month parts of the index.
So the output would look like following:

df3:

```
            x  y
dat          
2016-01-01  1  10 
2016-01-02  2  10
2016-01-03  3  10
2017-01-01  4  11
2017-01-02  5  11
2017-01-03  6  11
```

I have tried to join them using

```
df1.join(df2, how='inner')
```

and I know that I can extract year and month parts like so:

```
df1.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
df2.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

But I wonder how I can combine all these to achieve desired result?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information you want to merge on isn't explicitly defined anywhere.  And there isn't a nice to way to keep your dates in the index when we merge without destroying it.  So, we move the indices to the dataframe proper and create two new columns to merge on.  Namely, `year` and `month`.  I wrapped this part in a function to better see what's happening where.

```
def f(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    return df.assign(year=df.dat.dt.year, month=df.dat.dt.month)

df = f(df1).merge(f(df2), on=['year', 'month'], suffixes=['', '_'])

df.set_index('dat')[['x', 'y']]

            x   y
dat              
2016-01-01  1  10
2016-01-02  2  10
2016-01-03  3  10
2017-01-01  4  11
2017-01-02  5  11
2017-01-03  6  11
```

---

This is a different concept using `pd.Index.map` and `to_period`.  Create a dictionary mapping from `df2` that translates the year/month period object to the corresponding value in column `y`.  Then use `map` to map the period-ized dates in `df1.index` to the correct `y` values.

```
m = dict(zip(df2.index.to_period('M'), df2.y))
df1.assign(y=df1.index.to_period('M').map(m.get))

            x   y
dat              
2016-01-01  1  10
2016-01-02  2  10
2016-01-03  3  10
2017-01-01  4  11
2017-01-02  5  11
2017-01-03  6  11
```

---

**Setup**

```
dates1 = ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03',
          '2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1, 7)}, pd.DatetimeIndex(dates1, name='dat'))

dates2 = ['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01']
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y': [10, 11]}, pd.DatetimeIndex(dates2, name='dat'))
```

Comment: While this works, it is actually an expensive operation, because we need to shift around data between `Index` and the `Data` Columns. It surely does not count when working on DataFrames < 10 million rows but if you go into `dask`, merging on the `DateTimeIndex` sub-values (year,month,day in this example) would be way way faster, but I did not find a solution for merging on the subvalues of a `DateTimeIndex` in `dask` yet..

Answer (score 3):

You could use `merge` with `assign` on `year` and `month` from DateTimeIndex:

```
df3 = (df1.assign(year=df1.index.year, month=df1.index.month)
      .merge(df2.assign(year=df2.index.year, month=df2.index.month), on =['year','month'],right_index=True)
      .drop(['year','month'],axis=1))
```

Output:

```
            x   y
dat              
2016-01-01  1  10
2016-01-02  2  10
2016-01-03  3  10
2017-01-01  4  11
2017-01-02  5  11
2017-01-03  6  11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.join(df2, how='left').fillna(method = "ffill")
```